# Call PowerShell from C# Azure Function Apps

Tags: c#, .net, azure, powershell, azure-functions

I would like to run PowerShell commands in a V2 C# Azure Function App. I have tried to run PowerShell Core (which, as far as I know, is the only way I can access PS with .NET Core) from a .NET Core 2.1 Project in Visual Studio, which worked just fine, however, with a C# Azure Function App (which uses .NET Core) project I get the following error when I try to access the URL:

```
Executed 'Function1' (Failed, Id=dbb00673-938b-4d50-9576-9b3a4ec06c06) [2018-11-05 09:51:17] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Function1. AmberTest: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management.Automation, Version=6.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified. System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load the specified file.
```

I have the following NuGet packages installed (for PowerShell Core):

- Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Diagnostics 1.0.23
- Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK 6.1.0
- Microsoft.WSMan.Management 6.1.0

I could use a V1 Function App with PowerShell and get the desired functionality, but I want to know whether and how is it possible to call PowerShell from a C# Azure Function App.

Comment: Does my suggestion work for you? Feel free to ask if you are still hindered.  otherwise could you accept the answer to close your question?

Comment: It works like a charm! Thank you so much, and sorry the late response.

Comment: Hey, I want to achieve same thing. Run PowerShell command in C# Azure function in linux environment. Can you provide sample c# snippet for how to invoke command?

Comment: Jerry Liu's answer did fix the issue in question, but I faced new ones and because of time pressure I went with PS running on azure function. You might have better luck posting a new question about the problems you're still having after applying the answer from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that assemblies of runtimes i.e.`[FunctionProject]\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\bin\runtimes` folder are not loaded into function context so we see `Could not load file or assembly` error.

Workaround is to add those assemblies to `bin` i.e. `[FunctionProject]\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\bin` folder.

Right click on your function project, `Edit <FunctionProjectName>.csproj`.

Add content below. First item copies assemblies to publish directory and the second copy task is for local debug.

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <SDKVersion>6.1.0</SDKVersion>
    <SDKPlatform>win-x86</SDKPlatform>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\system.management\4.5.0\runtimes\win\lib\netcoreapp2.0\System.Management.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\system.management.automation\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Management.Automation.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.management.infrastructure\1.0.0\runtimes\win10-x86\lib\netstandard1.6\Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.powershell.commands.management\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.powershell.commands.utility\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.powershell.commands.diagnostics\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Diagnostics.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.powershell.sdk\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.powershell.security\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.Security.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.powershell.coreclr.eventing\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.CoreCLR.Eventing.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.powershell.consolehost\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.powershell.markdownrender\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.MarkdownRender.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.wsman.runtime\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.WSMan.Runtime.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.wsman.management\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.WSMan.Management.dll;
      ">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="CopyRuntimeToBin" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Copy SourceFiles="
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\system.management\4.5.0\runtimes\win\lib\netcoreapp2.0\System.Management.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\system.management.automation\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Management.Automation.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.management.infrastructure\1.0.0\runtimes\win10-x86\lib\netstandard1.6\Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.powershell.commands.management\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.powershell.commands.utility\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.powershell.commands.diagnostics\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Diagnostics.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.powershell.sdk\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.powershell.security\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.Security.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.powershell.coreclr.eventing\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.CoreCLR.Eventing.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.powershell.consolehost\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.powershell.markdownrender\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.MarkdownRender.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.wsman.runtime\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.WSMan.Runtime.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.wsman.management\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.WSMan.Management.dll;
      " DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)\bin" />
  </Target>
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions), PowerShell is not supported in V2.

[image]

Comment: While as of right now this is true, https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/585 and https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-powershell-worker suggest that PowerShell Function App is coming to V2. Still, my question remains unanswered, as I need access to PowerShell from C# Function App.

Comment: Yes goal is to have a private preview by the end of this calendar year.  As for this issue I’m not quite sure. Does it work locally? Does it work just in a regular .NET core console app?

Comment: With a regular .NET Core console app I can run PS Core commands, but I cannot do the same with an Azure Function project - that doesn't work, neither locally nor from Azure, as I get an error (the one I mentioned in my question) when I try to reach the provided URL.